# Can I sort the text after a certain character?

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++

I have a large list I'm trying to sort but I'd like to sort the list from the value after a certain character. eg:

```
241&name=A
123&name=C
645&name=B
```

So I'd like to sort the list alphabetically by "A, B, C" etc.  Can I do this in Notepad++ or Excel?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, managed to get it sorted through Notepad++

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Notepad++ Solution

1. "Menu" > "TextFX" > "TextFX Tools" and select one of the following:

   - Clear the check mark for option "+Sort ascending" to sort descending order.
   - Enable the check mark for option "+Sort ascending" to sort ascending order.

   [image]
2. Select the text, either lines of text or columns

   - For column mode select - Press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> down, select text with the  mouse

   [image]
3. "Menu" > "TextFX" > "TextFX Tools" and select one of the following:

   - "Sort lines case sensitive (at column)"
   - "Sort lines case insensitive (at column)"

   [image]
4. Result (before and after):

   [image] [image]

Notes:

> - TextFX Tools will sort only the lines you select. If you do a column mode select (Hold Shift + Alt keys down and select text via
>     mouse), then it will sort all the lines that are at least partly
>     selected, but will sort them according to the selected part.
> - The option "+Sort outputs only UNIQUE (at column) lines" can be checked independent of "+Sort ascending" option (meaning it will work
>     in either ascending or descending mode). When enabled, duplicate
>     entries will be removed when sorting, leaving only unique entries.
> - When using a rectangular selection, the sort key for a line is the part of that line that is within selection bounds.

Source [Sorting lines with plugin TextFX](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Sorting_Text)

---

#### What if I don't have the TextFX plugin?

Plugin Manager install:

The easiest way to install the plugin is to use the **Plugin Manager**

1. "Menu" > "Plugins" > "Plugin Manager" > "Show Plugin Manager"
2. Select the "Available"
3. Select "TextFX Characters"
4. Click " Install"

Manual install:

1. Close Notepad++
2. Download the zip file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/TextFX%20v0.26/
3. Extract to the Notepad++ `plugins` directory.
4. Run Notepad++

Comment: This solution requires an additional plugin which isn't present in my default installation of NotePad++. I am behind a corporate firewall and can't install it... :/

Comment: I use a portable version of Notepad++ on a USB stick for exactly that reason ;)

Comment: Now if only we were allowed to plug in USB sticks! (Bank policy, they are turned off. But we can use Excel!) :-(

Comment: According to Wikipedia (if you can believe it) "The first plugin to be **included** in the program was "TextFX", which includes features such as W3C validation for HTML and CSS, text sorting, character case alteration and quote handling."

Comment: @DenhamCoote As long as there is a way to download files to your system (USB, email, command line, ...) you will be able to add the plugin by downloading the necessary file and placing it in the correct folder. By using a portable version of Notepad++, you won't even have to install anything

Comment: @GroundZero Not without going through infosec. Not if I want to stay un-fired...

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, maybe they left it out of the copy I downloaded. I like, and prefer, your solution, but since the OP asked for Excel, it's a fair enough answer.

Comment: @DenhamCoote According to [TextFX menu is missing in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12699833), "It was removed from the default installation as it caused issues with certain configurations, and there's no maintainer."

Comment: Good update to your answer, I'm sure the additional install instructions will come in useful

Answer (score 12):

**Excel solution**

This solution will work for any length text after the `=`

1. Paste your data into Excel.
2. Use the formula `=MID(A1,FIND("=",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("=",A1))` to grab everything after the `=`
3. Sort on the new column

[image]

Comment: This solution requires an extra column of data :/

Comment: As does the other Excel solution. But this works for longer data. OP did ask for solutions in either...

Comment: @DavidPostill Anyone who has seriously worked with flat file databases for any length of time in production and doesn't have the control over the databases or the prioritization to get development resources to make changes, have had to make the compromise of adding key columns and concatenation columns in Excel for the purpose of sorting and slicing data effectively. Denham Coote solution addresses the issue the OP posed. It is quick, can be implemented by an end user, with little overhead if the database is actually larger than the key the OP posted. No need to be negative about it.

Comment: @AMR I wasn't being negative (I didn't downvote, in fact I upvoted both the answers that weren't mine), it was just an observation. The best solutions to any problem don't add to the data. For example the Notepad++ solution. I appreciate the Excel solution does require extra data ...

Comment: @DavidPostill's NotePad++ solution (which I upvoted, btw) doesn't need a big bloated piece of software to run, either ;-)

Answer (score 4):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=RIGHT(A1,1)
```

and copy down.  Then sort cols **A** and **B** by **B**:

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: This solution requires an extra column of data :/

Comment: @DavidPostill Clearly you are correct!

Comment: Unlike my Notepad++ solution ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill  I like your solution.....I am glad you posted it...Notepad++ looks really neat!  Is it free??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Although Notepad++ was mentioned in a different answer, I'll still reply to you: You can get Notepad++ for free at https://notepad-plus-plus.org/ If you had taken the effort to do a simple Google Search, you would've gotten this information immediately instead of having to wait 39minutes...

Answer (score 2):

There is a different solution with Notepad++ which doesn't require the extra plugin.
I used this input and I assumed that there aren't any # in the input. You could just use a different character for separating your sorting item from your original input.

```
123&name=Alpha&somethingelse
456&name=Gamma&differentstuff
789&name=Beta&otherstuff
```

1. Use a regular expression search & replace to copy the part you want to sort to the front of the line. Make sure to enable regular expressions and use

   `Search: (.*)&name=(.*?)&(.*)`

   `Replace: \2#\1&name=\2&\3`

Result:

```
Alpha#123&name=Alpha&somethingelse
Gamma#456&name=Gamma&differentstuff
Beta#789&name=Beta&otherstuff
```

2. Use the sort lines feature.

Result:

```
Alpha#123&name=Alpha&somethingelse
Beta#789&name=Beta&otherstuff
Gamma#456&name=Gamma&differentstuff
```

3. Use another regular expression to undo the changes from step 1.

   `Search: (.*)#(.*)`

   `Replace: \2`

Result:

```
123&name=Alpha&somethingelse
789&name=Beta&otherstuff
456&name=Gamma&differentstuff
```